# Como usar pseudônimos nas consultas usando Aliases junto com MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Gostaria de poder usar o Alias 'AS' junto com mysql sem precisar fazer alinhamento de consulta, ou seja, quero que as queries secundárias sejam nomeadas para usá-las na query principal, é possível?

Por exemplo, no caso abaixo o `AS` é usado de forma aninhada

> **Exemplo 1** com consultas dentro de consultas (e desse jeito **funciona**)

```
SELECT ID FROM (
    SELECT ID, msisdn FROM (
        SELECT * FROM TT2
    ) AS T
) AS T
```

A forma como gostaria de fazer seria sem aninhamento, assim:

> **Exemplo 2** com consultas externas em relação a consulta principal (desse jeito **não funciona**)

```
SELECT name, LEFT(occupation,1) AS letra FROM OCCUPATIONS ORDER BY name AS tab1;

SELECT letra FROM tab1 ORDER BY letra ASC;
```

> A principal diferença entre o exemplo 1 e 2, é que no primeiro caso as consultas estão aninhadas uma dentro da outra. A segunda consulta possui sub consultas fora da consulta principal.

A forma 2 não funciona, nem usando o parênteses, então, como fazer pra
usar um pseudo nome para a consulta ser representada temporariamente com um "*alias*" de forma não aninhada, isto é possível?

Comment: colocar um alias para um tabela (resultante da query) só faz sentido se for utilizar esse resultado em outra query. Não há motivo e nem onde isso seria retornado (pensando em linhas e colunas). Ou seja, onde seria utilizado esse `tab1` ?

Comment: Esqueci de colocar uma outra query usando a primeira como pseudo nome, veja se agora ficou melhor

Comment: veja se a resposta funciona

Comment: e entao jovem, resolveu ?

Comment: Pior que não, eu joguei a pergunta no SOen e disseram não ser possível até agora =\

Comment: Não entendo o down votes, a pergunta está bem clara e faz parte do escopo, essa mesma pergunta foi feita no SOen e teve 2 up votes, alguém pode sugerir melhorias para essa dúvida?

Comment: também não vejo o pq do down, coloquei o meu up...rs mas acredito que já esteja respondida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agora com a edição da pergunta, ficou mais claro. 
Nesse caso, você pode utilizar o `With`:

```
With tab1 as (
SELECT name,LEFT(occupation,1) AS letra FROM OCCUPATIONS ORDER BY name
)

SELECT letra FROM tab1 ORDER BY letra ASC;
```

Porém, essa cláusula só está disponível a partir da versão 8 do mysql. Em versões anteriores, as queries deverão ser aninhadas.

Comment: Aparentemente não, eu to testando na plataforma do hackerrank -> https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-pads/problem

Comment: depende da versão do mysql, salvo engano só está disponível a partir da versão 8. antes disso, só aninhando